# Making a div vertically centered causing it to be slightly horizontally off centered

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to make a `div` vertically centered using `CSS` position and transform method but apparently it is making the `div` slightly horizontally off centered. here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row container-fluid top_header">
      <div class="col-12 container-xl">
        <div class="top_header_texts"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top_header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 19% 90%, rgba(190, 190, 190,0.04) 0%, rgba(190, 190, 190,0.04) 17%,transparent 17%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 73% 2%, rgba(78, 78, 78,0.04) 0%, rgba(78, 78, 78,0.04) 94%,transparent 94%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 45% 2%, rgba(18, 18, 18,0.04) 0%, rgba(18, 18, 18,0.04) 55%,transparent 55%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 76% 60%, rgba(110, 110, 110,0.04) 0%, rgba(110, 110, 110,0.04) 34%,transparent 34%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 68% 56%, rgba(246, 246, 246,0.04) 0%, rgba(246, 246, 246,0.04) 16%,transparent 16%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 71% 42%, rgba(156, 156, 156,0.04) 0%, rgba(156, 156, 156,0.04) 47%,transparent 47%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 46% 82%, rgba(247, 247, 247,0.04) 0%, rgba(247, 247, 247,0.04) 39%,transparent 39%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 50% 47%, rgba(209, 209, 209,0.04) 0%, rgba(209, 209, 209,0.04) 45%,transparent 45%, transparent 100%),linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(84, 36, 210),rgb(44, 27, 154));
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  position: relative;
}

.top_header_texts {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: White;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Result: [image]

As you can see there's a little gap in the left but nothing in the right, this is nothing major but bothering me and couldn't get anything to sort this out

Comment: oh, forget to say, that text added via a script, so not in the html

Comment: Mention the other libraries you are useing, like you have used bootstrap here. Also post an executable code or link of jsfiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version of bootstrap. (4.1.1)

The `.container-fluid` and `.col-12` have padding attributes, and you can try to overwrite it by `.p-0` class

```
<div class="row container-fluid top_header p-0">
      <div class="col-12 container-xl p-0">
        <div class="top_header_texts"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Online Verification](http://jsfiddle.net/7e4pfryt/)

Answer (score 1):

Just a `text-align: center` fixes the problem, as you see:

```css
.top_header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 19% 90%, rgba(190, 190, 190,0.04) 0%, rgba(190, 190, 190,0.04) 17%,transparent 17%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 73% 2%, rgba(78, 78, 78,0.04) 0%, rgba(78, 78, 78,0.04) 94%,transparent 94%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 45% 2%, rgba(18, 18, 18,0.04) 0%, rgba(18, 18, 18,0.04) 55%,transparent 55%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 76% 60%, rgba(110, 110, 110,0.04) 0%, rgba(110, 110, 110,0.04) 34%,transparent 34%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 68% 56%, rgba(246, 246, 246,0.04) 0%, rgba(246, 246, 246,0.04) 16%,transparent 16%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 71% 42%, rgba(156, 156, 156,0.04) 0%, rgba(156, 156, 156,0.04) 47%,transparent 47%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 46% 82%, rgba(247, 247, 247,0.04) 0%, rgba(247, 247, 247,0.04) 39%,transparent 39%, transparent 100%),radial-gradient(circle at 50% 47%, rgba(209, 209, 209,0.04) 0%, rgba(209, 209, 209,0.04) 45%,transparent 45%, transparent 100%),linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(84, 36, 210),rgb(44, 27, 154));
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.top_header .col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.top_header_texts {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: White;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="row container-fluid top_header">
      <div class="col-12 container-xl">
        <div class="top_header_texts">text</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not in my case, it is just making the text center:
![Valid XHTML](https://i.ibb.co/m9QxCWn/Screenshot-20200322-131604.png)

Comment: I edited that for you. FLEX can fix it and no need to use absolute position

Answer (score 1):

`container-fluid` and `container-xl` classes of bootstrap brings `padding-left:15px`. try setting it to zero.

HTML:

```
<div class="row container-fluid top_header paddingLeft_0">
  <div class="col-12 container-xl paddingLeft_0">
    <div class="top_header_texts"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.paddingLeft_0 {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: so, adding it caused similar gap on right side, I reset the padding 0 for all side and everthing seems ok now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use .text-center or .mx-auto to keep content on the center

Comment: you mean the text or the div?

Comment: ha  vai..tumi j div or text center e nita chaw seitai text-center use koro...

Comment: i'm not talking about the text though, I can do it using text-align, i'm talking about the div itself

Comment: if you want to keep div on the center you need to use mx-auto...but first you need to control the div width must..